# How can I store widget screenshot as jpg file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have taken a widget screenshot and I want to save it as .jpg file. I was able to save it as .png file below but I don't know how to save it as .jpg file. Here is my code:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _repainkey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory());
print(directory.path);
File imgFile = new File('${directory.path}/flutter2.png');
await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to do a file type conversion. You can use the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) to help you do this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51042816/13250142) is very similar to what you're looking for, just doing the conversion reversed from what you want.

Example from the linked answer:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read a jpeg image from file.
  Image image = decodeImage(new File('test.jpg').readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  new File('out/thumbnail-test.png')
    ..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

---

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read a jpeg image from file.
  Image image = decodeImage(new File('test.png').readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  new File('out/thumbnail-test.jpg')
    ..writeAsBytesSync(encodeJpg(thumbnail));
}
```

Comment: thank you it is working, but I wrote it as ..writeAsBytes(encodeJpg(..)). Is there a diffference between  writeAsBytes() and writeAsBytesSync() ?

Comment: @hborah One is a synchronous function and the other is async.

Comment: question is related to save image as jpg not png. how to create png to jpg, please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh If  you really cannot figure that out from the code shown here or the linked answer, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore could you please suggest me how can we convert a png image to jpg image? Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh No I will not in the comments here. If you have trouble understanding how to change this code to do jpg instead of png encoding I recommend you ask a separate question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thanks for your prompt reply. But query is "How can I store widget screenshot as jpg file in flutter?" which is clearly saying that output should be jpg while your code may be generate a png image instead of jpg.

Comment: @Kamlesh Yes and the OP was able to correctly assess how to do the reverse of what I posted.

Comment: @Kamles Then ask a new question. The code clearly helped the OP. If you don't believe the answer is helpful, down vote and move on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jpeg_encode](https://pub.dev/packages/jpeg_encode) library. It would allow you to convert your ui.Image object to a jpeg without the intermediary step of converting to a png, and is thus likely to be faster.