# How to convert png image to jpg format in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm looking for ways through which I can convert png images to jpg format in flutter as I'm unable to find a way to do that anywhere.

This is the code I tried but it is giving me black images:

```dart
// Read a jpeg image from file.
 img.Image image = img.decodeImage(File(pngfilepath).readAsBytesSync());

// Resize the image to a 200 height thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
 img.Image thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, height: 200);

// Save the thumbnail as a JPG.
 File(outputfilepath/filename.jpg)
   ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(thumbnail));
```

So, please provide me a way in which I can convert png to jpg. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image). in the example section you can see how to change `.webp` image to `PNG` format.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main() {
  // Read an image from file (webp in this case).
  // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
  // decoder.
  final image = decodeImage(File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync())!;

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  final thumbnail = copyResize(image, width: 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

---

PNG to JPEG:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main() {
  final image = decodeImage(File('test.png').readAsBytesSync())!;

  File('thumbnail.jpg').writeAsBytesSync(encodeJpg(image));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for png to jpg not webp to png.

Comment: its just an example, you can change the formats based of your need, follow the updated answer.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but as I have already described my issue in my post above that I have tried to modify this code but it didn't work as it is resulting in black images.

Comment: ok, it is due to the difference between png and jpg, what is your pic?

Comment: The pic I'm using is this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg/1200px-QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg.png.
I did try to encode it using both encodePng and encodeJpg with for example output path as (filepath/filename.jpg) but the resulting image is always invalid.

Comment: would you please try the code using another pic? let me know the result.

Comment: I used this image this time - https://pixabay.com/illustrations/water-splash-png-2748640/
This is the image which I got from encodeJpg- https://ibb.co/njJTZnX (Weird Image).
This is the image which I got from encodePng- https://ibb.co/dL4X7H4 (In this transparency is still there).
This is what I got from an online tool - https://ibb.co/Jvc3cTn (No transparency which is what I want).

Comment: transparency only is supported in PNG format and JPG format does not support it, so I think this algorithm works well

Comment: No devices are still treating the jpg as png because we have just  changed the extension in case two above. The image is still encoded in png so it will be treated as png by modern devices. What I want is the last case which I got from online tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert a PNG to JPG (with the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image)) you can use this code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main(List<String> args) {
  // Read a png image from file.
  img.Image image = img.decodeImage(
      File("image.png").readAsBytesSync())!;

  // Resize the image to a 200 height thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  img.Image thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, height: 200);

  if (thumbnail.numChannels == 4) {
    var imageDst = img.Image(
      width: thumbnail.width,
      height: thumbnail.height,
    ) // default format is uint8 and numChannels is 3 (no alpha)
    ..clear(
      img.ColorRgb8(255, 255, 255),
    ); // clear the image with the color white.

    thumbnail = img.compositeImage(
      imageDst,
      thumbnail,
    ); // alpha composite the image onto the white background
  }

  // Save the thumbnail as a JPG.
  File("thumbnail.jpg").writeAsBytesSync(
    img.encodeJpg(thumbnail),
  );
}
```

---

Using the [Command](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Command-class.html) base class

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;


void main(List<String> args) async {

  final cmd = img.Command()
        // Read a png image from file.
        ..decodeImage(File("image.png").readAsBytesSync())
        // Resize the image to a 200 height thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
        ..copyResize(
          height: 200,
        )
        ..filter((image) {
          if (image.numChannels == 4) {
            var imageDst = img.Image(
              width: image.width,
              height: image.height,
            ); // default format is uint8 and numChannels is 3 (no alpha)
            imageDst.clear(
              img.ColorRgb8(255, 255, 255),
            ); // clear the image with the color white.
            return img.compositeImage(
              imageDst,
              image,
            ); // alpha composite the image onto the white background
          }

          return image;
        })
        // Save the thumbnail as a JPG.
        ..encodeJpg()
        ..writeToFile("thumbnail.jpg");

    await cmd.executeThread();
}
```

These 2 solutions remove the transparency from the png file and replace it with a white background before getting the resulting jpg file and this is based on this comment from github: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/453#issuecomment-1380995783