# How to convert jp2 to jpeg (or just decode jp2) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, jpeg, decoding

Does anyone know some tools or some approach to convert jp2 bytes array to jpeg or some another image type in Flutter?
I know about [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) but here is not implemented some tools for decode jp2 bytes array.

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042665/convert-jpg-image-to-png-image-in-flutter-ios).

Comment: @gretal Thank you, but I ask about jp2 format. Not jpeg or jpg.

Comment: There are no packages for Dart/Flutter that handle JPEG2000, unfortunately. Your best bet would be to convert the files at the source (if you're not loading them from the device). Otherwise, you'll have to create a web service for that (or use an existing cloud service).